# отношение чисел

Tags: математика

Может кто доходчиво объяснить как вычислять такие значения. Пусть
даны две пары чисел (1,3) и (0,100).
При значении 0 из второй пары, значение в первой равно 1, при 100 соответственно 3.
Значение между нулем и сотней может меняться, как рассчитывать при его изменении значение между единицей и тройкой?
Не могу въехать в пропорции, прошу доходчивого понятного объяснения!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я понимаю, мы говорим о линейной зависимости.

Попробуйте нарисовать график - прямую между точками (1,0) и (3,100) - вот когда вы "едете" по ней по горизонтали, то вертикальная координата будет давать значение между 0 и 100...

А формулами... Смотрите - расстояние между 1 и 3 равно 2. Если у нас есть значение `x` - то оно отстоит от 1 на расстоянии `x-1`, что составляет `(x-1)/(3-1)` *часть* от всего расстояния от 1 до 3.

Но ту же часть должно составлять расстояние соответствующей точки `y` от 0 по отношению к расстоянию от 0 до 100, т.е. `(y-0)/(100-0)`. Приравниваем эти части: `(x-1)/(3-1) = (y-0)/(100-0)`

Ну, или `y = 50x - 50` - при `x=1` имеем `y=0`, при `x=3` получаем `y=100`...